# Nano.auth fails when require_valid_user = true

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, couchdb, couchdb-nano

Below is my sample code referring to this doc:

https://github.com/dscape/nano#using-cookie-authentication

```
var nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984')
const username = 'test'
const userpass = '123123'
const callback = console.log // this would normally be some callback
const cookies = {} // store cookies, normally redis or something

nano.auth(username, userpass, function (err, body, headers)
{
   if (err)
   {
    return callback(err);
   }

   if (headers && headers['set-cookie'])
   {
    cookies[username] = headers['set-cookie'];
    console.log(cookies)
   }

   if (!err)
   {
    callback("success ", "it worked");
   }
});
```

It works perfectly when my `require_valid_user = false`

```
   { test:
   [ 'AuthSession=dGVzdDo1QTQ1RTFENDoVzjtA5v82S3bJRyI9Mz_J9dXrWA; Version=1; 
   Expires=Thu, 28-Dec-2017 22:43:56 GMT; Max-Age=600; Path=/; HttpOnly' ] }
   //success  it worked
```

However, when I set `require_valied_user = true` , it fails with the following error:

> name: 'Error',   error: 'unauthorized',   reason: 'Authentication
>   required.',   scope: 'couch',   statusCode: 401,   request:    {
>   method: 'POST',
>        headers:
>         { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
>           accept: 'application/json' },
>        uri: 'http://localhost:5984/_session',
>        body: 'name=test&password=123123' },   headers:    { 'www-authenticate': 'Basic realm="server"',
>        date: 'Fri, 29 Dec 2017 06:42:10 GMT',
>        'content-type': 'application/json',
>        'cache-control': 'must-revalidate',
>        statusCode: 401,
>        uri: 'http://localhost:5984/_session' },   errid: 'non_200',
>   description: 'couch returned 401' }

I am not sure what I am doing wrongly as it suppose to work both ways?